# Update column from a table with specific condition and counter ( Unexpected result )

Tags: mysql, database

I want to know what is the query of this condition? I want update a column with counter but my counter have to reset group by. Let me explain it with an example:

```
   Data set:
  +----+------------+----------+------+-------+
  | id | content_id | title_id | path | order |
  +----+------------+----------+------+-------+
  |  1 |          1 |       20 | NJ   |     0 |
  |  2 |          1 |       20 | CA   |     0 |
  |  3 |          1 |       20 | LA   |     0 |
  |  4 |          1 |       20 | MM   |     0 |
  |  5 |          1 |       30 | AX   |     0 |
  |  6 |          1 |       30 | ER   |     0 |
  |  7 |          2 |       10 | NJ   |     0 |
  |  8 |          2 |       10 | CA   |     0 |
  |  9 |          2 |       20 | AX   |     0 |
  | 10 |          2 |       20 | CA   |     0 |
  | 11 |          2 |       30 | FF   |     0 |
  | 12 |          2 |       30 | EE   |     0 |
  +----+------------+----------+------+-------+

  Desired result set:
  +----+------------+----------+------+-------+
  | id | content_id | title_id | path | order |
  +----+------------+----------+------+-------+
  |  1 |          1 |       20 | NJ   |     1 |
  |  2 |          1 |       20 | CA   |     1 |
  |  3 |          1 |       20 | LA   |     1 |
  |  4 |          1 |       20 | MM   |     1 |
  |  5 |          1 |       30 | AX   |     2 |
  |  6 |          1 |       30 | ER   |     2 |
  |  7 |          2 |       10 | NJ   |     1 |
  |  8 |          2 |       10 | CA   |     1 |
  |  9 |          2 |       20 | AX   |     2 |
  | 10 |          2 |       20 | CA   |     2 |
  | 11 |          2 |       30 | FF   |     3 |
  | 12 |          2 |       30 | EE   |     3 |
  +----+------------+----------+------+-------+
```

I use below query but "order" is can not reset when "content" is changed.

```
set @counter = 0;
update paper as t, (select (@counter := @counter+1) as cou, t2.title_id
from paper as t2 group by t2.title_id) as t3 
set t.order = t3.cou where t.title_id = t3.title_id;
```

and I use below query too with no success:

```
set @counter = 0;
update paper as t, (select (@counter := @counter+1) as cou, t2.title_id 
from paper as t2 group by t2.title_id, t2.content_id) as t3
set t.order = t3.cou where t.title_id = t3.title_id;
```

**Edit:**
I added my table schema to sqlfiddle. [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b1a7/1) (Thank you @Payam)

Comment: -1? Why? What is wrong? @Payam

Comment: I just edited your post, I did not downvote your question. I guess your question is a bit ambiguous, try to create an instance of your database in [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: I added sqlfiddle link with my table schema and the update query. Thank you for your suggest @Payam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way, but there's possibly a more elegant solution...

```
 UPDATE paper a
   JOIN 
      ( 

        SELECT p.id 
             , p.content_id 
             , p.title_id 
             , p.path 
             , IF(@prev_content = content_id,
                           IF(@prev_title = title_id,@i:=@i,@i:=@i+1)
                  ,@i:=1) new_order
             , @prev_title := title_id
             , @prev_content := content_id 
          FROM paper p
             , (SELECT @i:=0,@prev_content:=NULL,@prev_title:=NULL) vars 
         ORDER 
            BY id

      ) b
     ON b.id = a.id
    SET a.order = b.new_order;
```

Comment: Can you merge your query with update statement? Your query seems look correct but when I used it on update statement, I didn't get the result that I excepted. @Strawberry

Comment: I can, but are you sure you want to store information which (as we've just demonstrated) can be easily calcuated on-the-fly?

Comment: I have already a table with 125001 records and I can't do that with server side ( PHP, Java, ... ) for some limitation. I can do only on phpmyadmin and I have to run update query with your select statement query. I've tested your query and it's correct and thank you about that, I would be appreciated if merge it with update query.

Comment: I changed your order by from id to content_id, title_id and then the query works perfectly. Thank you very much. I just accept the answer